# Can't Share Tweet containing quote & author (FCC Random Quote Machine) Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter

My JSON works fine. I'm able to modify the quote-text and the quote-author every time I click my "Gimme A' Quote" button. However, I'm experiencing problems each time I try to post a tweet using the quote's text and author. Whenever I click on the twitter symbol, the page just refreshes.

I've been trying to add the quote content and author into the Tweet by doing this:

```
var twitterIntent = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + quoteText + 'Author' + quoteAuthor + ' @myleschuahiock';
```

And subsequently telling JQuery to do this whenever I click on the "Gimme A' Quote" button:

```
$('.quote-button').click(function(){
    getQuote();
    colorRandomizer();
    $('.twitter-share').attr("href", twitterIntent);
});
```

My code is located here:
http://codepen.io/myleschuahiock/pen/WrVgzB 
Please take a look!

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks and much appreciated!

This project is my submission for Free Code Camp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining `twitterIntent` inside of the `getQuote()` function, but then trying to use it outside of that function. If you check the console for errors it shows that `twitterIntent` is uindefined after you click the button. Instead, you can just change the `href` attribute of the `.twitter-share` link inside of the `getQuote()` function.

Just add the line `$('.twitter-share').attr('href','https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='+quoteText+' Author: '+quoteAuthor+' @myleschuahiock');` where you are changing the contents of the `.quote-content` and `.quote-author` areas like the example below.

```
json.forEach(function(val) {
    quoteText = val.quote;
    quoteAuthor = val.author;
    $('.quote-content').html(quoteText);
    $('.quote-author').html(quoteAuthor);
    $('.twitter-share').attr('href','https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='+quoteText+' Author: '+quoteAuthor+' @myleschuahiock');
  });
```

Then all you have to do is remove `$('.twitter-share').attr("href", twitterIntent);` from `$('.quote-button').click()`, and you're all set.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for simplifying my code as well! @ShamSUP !